# Why modRewrite applies automatic .php to this simple rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok guys i have maybe a stupid problem, but i'm probably dumb :)

I have this simple .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)$               news-inside.php?n=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^news/?$                  news.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Every time i try to get into first rule by typing some urls like these:

http://host/news/something

i get redirected to the file news.php, not to news-inside.php with the query string!

looking at the $_GET and $_SERVER of the reached page, this is the result:

```
$_GET => empty

$_SERVER (some)

  'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'QUERY_STRING' => string '' (length=0)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/news/something' (length=15)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/news.php' (length=9)
  'PATH_INFO' => string '/something' (length=10)
  'PATH_TRANSLATED' => string '/var/www/rolo/something' (length=23)
  'PHP_SELF' => string '/news.php/something' (length=19)
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to disable [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews):

```
Options -MultiViews
```